# Does type alignment modify type size?

Tags: c++

I wrote following code and tested it on gcc:

```
// firstly some platform-specific workarounds
#if _MSC_VER
#define ALN_BEGIN(x) __declspec(align(x)) 
#define ALN_END(x)
#define alignof(x) __alignof(x)
#else
#define ALN_BEGIN(x)
#define ALN_END(x) __attribute__((aligned(x)))
#define alignof(x) __alignof__(x)
#endif

// struct have three 4-byte members, but aligned at 32 byte
ALN_BEGIN(32) struct Foo
{
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
} ALN_END(32);

// show its size and alignment
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("size %d, alignment%d\n", sizeof(Foo), alignof(Foo));
}
```

When I compile it using gcc and run, although Foo only has 12 bytes for all its members, `sizeof(Foo)` got 32 which is alignment size. So does the size expansion is according to language standard （which is reliable) or it is only a feature for GCC?

I'm making an object pool class, so I have to precisely work with type size and alignment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is consistent with the standard. `sizeof (X)` is basically defined as the offset in bytes between the starting addresses of two consecutive `X` objects in an array. If such objects cannot follow each other tightly due to alignment restrictions, `sizeof` increases accordingly.

Quoting C++14, 5.3.3/2:

> ... When applied
>   to a class, the result is the number of bytes in an object of that class **including any padding required for
>   placing objects of that type in an array**. ... When applied
>   to an array, the result is the total number of bytes in the array. This implies that the size of an array of *n*
>   elements is *n* times the size of an element.

(Emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1):

The result of `sizeof`, for any type (except `char` types, which have size `1` by definition), is implementation defined, and is affected by alignment.   However, if

- `sizeof(float)` is `4`;
- your struct contains three `floats`; AND
- both beginning and end of the struct are aligned to 32 byte boundaries.

then you can expect the behaviour you see.